# change content of div based on usergroup

Tags: jquery

I have a static block that loads an image with a link on the main page. However what I need is if the user is logged in and is a wholesaler to have the image have a different url. So I am using jquery which I have loaded in our Magento CE website. My issue is it does not seem to be changing the url. However when I look at the code inspector in Chrome I do not see any errors?
What happens is even when I am logged in my div with id demo does not have the wholesale content in it.

Here is my code (which I have in the header.phtml file)

```
       <?php
            //switch url for brestcancer awareness month 
            //slider that links to a product
         if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
            {
                // Get group Id
                $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
                //Get customer Group name
                $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
                $agroupcodename = $group->getCode();

                 if($agroupcodename =='US-Wholesale')
                    {
       ?>

                        <script>
                             jQuery('#demo').html('<p><a href="https://www.*********.com/hair/hair-color/hair-color-wholesale#92=27" title="Breast Cancer Awareness Month"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/main_page_images/sliders/Pink_BCRF_homepage.jpg"}}" alt="Breast Cancer Awareness Month" /></a></p>');
                        </script>
       <?php
                    }
           }
        ?>
```

I then have a static we will call slider1

```
      <div id="demo">
           <p>
               <a href="https://www.*******.com/hair-color#92=27" title="Breast Cancer Awareness Month"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/main_page_images/sliders/Pink_BCRF_homepage.jpg"}}" alt="Breast Cancer Awareness Month" /></a>
           </p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#demo').html('<p><a href="https://www.*********.com/hair/hair-color/hair-color-wholesale#92=27" title="Breast Cancer Awareness Month"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/main_page_images/sliders/Pink_BCRF_homepage.jpg"}}" alt="Breast Cancer Awareness Month" /></a></p>');
});
</script>
```